dexie cloud db entries with image blob disapear
Hy there
I have been using some db entries containing small image blobs.
It works fine with dexie js.
But with dexie cloud, these db entries that contain image blobs, disapear somehow.
Just after saving it to de db i can still get the entrie, but then it is gone.
Probably after syncing to the dexie cloud.
Im also getting the following "rejection" in the sync response:
Sync response 
Object { changes: (2) […], rejections: (1) […], dbId: "z9c1xige1", realms: (2) […], inviteRealms: [], serverRevision: "1:317", schema: {…} }
​
changes: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
dbId: "z9c1xige1"
​
inviteRealms: Array []
​
realms: Array [ "rlm-public", "retotito@gmail.com" ]
​
rejections: Array [ {…} ]
​​
0: Object { name: "ReferenceError", message: "XMLHttpRequest is not defined", txid: "hhHZyDkl5JgoEhDQDnts+g==" }
​​​
message: "XMLHttpRequest is not defined"
​​​
name: "ReferenceError"
​​​
txid: "hhHZyDkl5JgoEhDQDnts+g=="
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
length: 1
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
schema: Object { notes: {…}, roles: {…}, images: {…}, … }
​​
"$baseRevs": Object { idPrefix: "$bs", primaryKey: "[tableName+clientRev]", initiallySynced: true }
​​
"$jobs": Object { idPrefix: "$jb", initiallySynced: true }
​​
"$logins": Object { idPrefix: "$lg", primaryKey: "claims.sub", initiallySynced: true }
​​
"$syncState": Object { idPrefix: "$sy", initiallySynced: true }
​​
images: Object { idPrefix: "img", primaryKey: "id", markedForSync: true, … }
​​
members: Object { idPrefix: "mmb", primaryKey: "id", generatedGlobalId: true, … }
​​
notebooks: Object { idPrefix: "Ntb", primaryKey: "id", markedForSync: true, … }
​​
notebooks_tree: Object { idPrefix: "ntb", primaryKey: "id", markedForSync: true, … }
​​
notes: Object { idPrefix: "nts", primaryKey: "id", markedForSync: true, … }
​​
realms: Object { idPrefix: "rlm", primaryKey: "realmId", generatedGlobalId: true, … }
​​
recycle_bin: Object { idPrefix: "rcy", primaryKey: "id", markedForSync: true, … }
​​
roles: Object { idPrefix: "rls", primaryKey: "[realmId+name]", markedForSync: true, … }
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
serverRevision: "1:317"

Unfortunatily i can't figure out, how to solve this issue.
Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Please read [ask], then edit your question to provide all relevant details (a [mcve]). Right now it's just a general description and a (very large, unformatted) output (I added basic formatting for readability).
